# Time on Windows 10 - XAMPP - PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am on a windows 10 computer, my computer timing is  9:29:30 AM

The following PHP code shows wrong time

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

the datetime it shows is **2017-02-27 17:36:08**, how is that possible? the date is right.

My Computer is set in Mountain Time

[image]

Comment: your server is probably setup in a different time zone.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: `echo date_default_timezone_get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your server is set for plain UTC, but you're in PST zone. This is totally fine, and in fact something that I highly recommend, [UTC for storage/computation, any other TZ is solely for output formatting] you just need to be a bit more explicit with your timezones when formatting output.

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$pst = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$utc_time = new DateTime('now', $utc);
$pst_time = new DateTime('now', $pst);

var_dump(
    $utc_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    $pst_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

Output:

```
string(19) "2017-02-27 18:20:09"
string(19) "2017-02-27 10:20:09"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there, by any chance,
a problem with the GMT-format of your php or apache2 version?
Like your computer recognizes that you live, let's say,
in Washington, but the script checks for London's time?
[because London has GMT +0]

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your timezone:

Either edit php.ini (\xampp\php\php.ini) `date.timezone value` in [Date] section:

`date.timezone = YourTimezone`

or edit  my.ini (\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini) add or replace

`default-time-zone = YourTimezone`

Restart Apache and MySQL

Comment: my computer is set in mountain time

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to the following and the issue was sorted

```
ini_set("date.timezone", "America/Denver");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: That's what I was [suggesting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42491073/1405376) to do :-)